Unable to decrypt JWE Token from Python jwcrypt to NodeJS jose
I am unable to decrypt a JWE Token generated by jwcrypt (Python library for JWE Encryption and Decryption) to jose (Javascript library for JWE Encryption and Decryption)
I have explicitly defined the A256KW and A256CBC-HS512 on both jwcrypt and jose as well. I also need to provide a "Secret Key" to the JWK's "k" parameter, which will be used for the Symmetric Encryption and Decryption.
Below is the Javascript code for jose


import {
  CompactEncrypt,
  compactDecrypt,
  CompactDecryptResult,
  KeyLike,
  importJWK,
} from 'jose';

class JweService {

  async createSecretKey(jwtKey: string): Promise<KeyLike | Uint8Array> {
    const base64Key = Buffer.from(jwtKey).toString('base64');

    return importJWK(
      {
        kty: 'oct',
        use: 'enc',
        k: base64Key
      },
      'A256KW',
    );
  }

  async createAccessToken(
    payload,
    secretKey: KeyLike | Uint8Array,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();

    return new CompactEncrypt(encoder.encode(payload))
      .setProtectedHeader({
        alg: 'A256KW',
        enc: 'A256CBC-HS512',
      })
      .encrypt(secretKey);
  }

  async decryptAccessToken(
    token: string,
    secretKey: KeyLike | Uint8Array,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    const { plaintext }: CompactDecryptResult = await compactDecrypt(
      token,
      secretKey,
    );

    return decoder.decode(plaintext);
  }
}



This is how I use the JweService


  async createAccessTokenForDemo(reqBody): Promise<string> {
    const secretKey = await this.jweService.createSecretKey(
      'QEO89KnZ8GJNAZEhBGRlQaBVtuA9asd2',
    );

    return this.jweService.createAccessToken(
      JSON.stringify(reqBody),
      secretKey,
    );
  }

  async decryptAccessTokenForDemo(reqBody): Promise<any> {
    const secretKey = await this.jweService.createSecretKey(
      'QEO89KnZ8GJNAZEhBGRlQaBVtuA9asd2',
    );

    const decrypted = await this.jweService.decryptAccessToken(
      reqBody.Token,
      secretKey,
    );

    return JSON.parse(decrypted);
  }



Now for Python which uses jwcrypto:


from jwcrypto import jwk, jwe
from jwcrypto.common import json_encode
import base64

def create_secret_key(jwt_key, alg='A256KW'):
    jwt_key_bytes = jwt_key.encode('utf-8')  # Convert string to bytes
    jwt_key_base64 = base64.b64encode(jwt_key_bytes)  # Base64 encode the bytes

    return jwk.JWK.generate(
        kty = "oct",
        use = "enc",
        k = jwt_key_base64,
        alg = alg
    )

def create_access_token(payload, secret_key, alg='A256KW', enc='A256CBC-HS512'):
    jwetoken = jwe.JWE(payload.encode('utf-8'), json_encode({"alg": alg, "enc": enc}))
    jwetoken.add_recipient(secret_key)
    return jwetoken.serialize(compact=True)

def decrypt_access_token(token, secret_key):
    jwetoken = jwe.JWE()
    jwetoken.deserialize(token)
    jwetoken.decrypt(secret_key)
    return jwetoken.payload.decode('utf-8')

# Secret key and payload
jwt_key = 'QEO89KnZ8GJNAZEhBGRlQaBVtuA9asd2'
payload = '{"name": "John"}'

# Create secret key
secret_key = create_secret_key(jwt_key)

# Create JWE access token
access_token = create_access_token(payload, secret_key)
print("Encrypted Payload:", access_token)

# Decrypt JWE access token
decrypted_payload = decrypt_access_token(access_token, secret_key)

print("Decrypted Payload:", decrypted_payload)



This is an example JWE Token from the Python script:
(When decrypted using NodeJS jose, jose library returns an error of "Error: decryption operation failed")
Encrypted JWE token: b'eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIn0.4xd2sw9FFFBZjzOo7ofz-Y7M_rUK_2-DACZPZyvVEHtFVa29eOu43s5rCtlh3xP8_9oMBOuoWXnzJWLEOyxyzl3axDYo-a8Y.QH-iHG2dqduw6r8agd5ZIg.W7MmKBaBEe5EwaGTHfXAUI2MhPFOHMGA5ZkHBNHWqUY.xRUr1jaYxwN5JDkazJ6mQYeSafiXCeidgPurl9qMJLs'
Decrypted JWE token: b'{"name": "John Doe"}'

Is there any configuration I am missing? or is there some encoding that is different between NodeJS and Python behind the scenes which could be the reason why?

This is not reproducible: The posted token can be decrypted with the posted key and NodeJS code, see online: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/13Af

Hi @Topaco I have generated new JWE tokens, for some reason, I am not able to decrypt them anymore in NodeJS. Encrypted Payload: eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIn0.c8uqoqjjX8NMditN5FxoR370s2SStS3l2MyAICjMOpPPgoGMKvJXe4Uc1oPuEDCN4ErnRHTQCV0rv1ufuBGVHPrVquEA6FUg.lHpvKOITrWmPy_KjD1VAJA.2-Jqr7ilFdyou0Fd7OiYR_xEGpcmIDQ8XBsq-vyG68M.buxzj5_Nr-xjoBiU8oLcQYbW7vAAlBEbX7H3rxZj3Jw Decrypted Payload: {"name": "John"}

The token posted in your last comment cannot be decrypted with the posted key even with the Python code! The reason is an inconsistent key, for details see my answer.

In the Python code, a new, random 32 bytes key is generated in create_secret_key() with jwk.JWK.generate() with each call. The passed jwt_key is ignored (i.e. k is not the Base64url encoding of QEO8... at all). This can be easily verified by exporting the generated key with secret_key.export() and comparing the k parameter.
As a consequence, the decryption of the token with the NodeJS code fails when the key QEO8... is applied.

To import a key (instead of generating a new one), the following implementation can be used, s. here:
def create_secret_key(jwt_key, alg='A256KW'):
    jwt_key_bytes = jwt_key.encode('utf-8')  
    jwt_key_base64url = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(jwt_key_bytes).replace(b"=", b"").decode('utf-8')  

    key = {
        'kty': 'oct',
        'use': 'enc',
        'k': jwt_key_base64url,
        "alg": alg
    }
    
    return jwk.JWK(**key)

Also note that the implementation applies Base64url and not Base64 as defined for JWKs.
With the following code:
jwt_key = 'QEO89KnZ8GJNAZEhBGRlQaBVtuA9asd2'
secret_key = create_secret_key(jwt_key)
print('Key:' + secret_key.export()) 

the import can be checked: k is UUVPODlLblo4R0pOQVpFaEJHUmxRYUJWdHVBOWFzZDI, which corresponds to the Base64url encoding of QEO89KnZ8GJNAZEhBGRlQaBVtuA9asd2.

Also in the corresponding method in the NodeJS code, Base64url must be used instead of Base64:
async createSecretKey(jwtKey) {
    const base64urlKey = Buffer.from(jwtKey).toString('base64url');

    return importJWK(
        {
            kty: 'oct',
            use: 'enc',
            k: base64urlKey
        },
        'A256KW',
    );
}


Now, if an encrypted token is generated with the fixed Python code, e.g.
eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIn0.BAhqPzCOT6u0xEGd40z6sYBU7XWJqwLMWxY1L6B2YYK0YdLvVe6WA8ypHJ6Q0cm4TWFw2xL4n6DeqqyoC9zkEd4fLqU04U4D.pK_f_0tBwXIj7hy79IjC2g.9vtRX6kKCBFoPD2UcfuUyIMevY3d7Pj7ydOM9XBWiJU.cYVtCc9O_8xuBxXg21316rmeNA2NHYPLF3NOjk7RSrw

this can be decrypted with the key QEO8... and the adapted NodeJS code.
